# Windows Server Backup , MMC could not create the snap-in.

Tags: windows, backup, mmc

I have installed windows server 2012 r2 
I installed windows back up feature which was working fine. But suddenly 
it is throwing the exception MMC could not create the snap-in.

I have searched but couldnt find the solution.

I then removed the feature and added it again but still the same 
Please Help